# Days before every end of month

Tags: python, string, list, datetime

How to get '2018/01/29', '2018/02/26' which are second days before every end of month, such as from the daylist below in Python?

```
daylist=['2018/01/25','2018/01/26','2018/01/29','2018/01/30','2018/01/31','2018/02/01','2018/02/20','2018/02/23','2018/02/26','2018/02/27','2018/02/28','2018/03/02']
```

(Every secondays can be obtained by daylist[-2::-2], but I have no idea how to get second days before every end of the month)

Comment: Are you trying to find the second day before the end of _any_ given month, or are you trying to find which of those date strings represents the second day before the end of its month?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by checking if a date is the end of a month, then subtracting two days to get the date two days before that. Ex:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

daylist=['2018/01/25','2018/01/26','2018/01/29','2018/01/30','2018/01/31','2018/02/01','2018/02/20','2018/02/23','2018/02/26','2018/02/27','2018/02/28','2018/03/02']

# parse to datetime first
dt_list = [datetime.strptime(d, "%Y/%m/%d") for d in daylist]

# now shift each date by one day and see if the month changes - if so,
# you have a month end...
two_days_before_end = []
for dt in dt_list:
    # assumes the dt_list is sorted:
    if (dt + timedelta(days=1)).month != dt.month:
        two_days_before_end.append(dt-timedelta(days=2))

print(two_days_before_end)
# [datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 26, 0, 0)]
```